# symfony jquery he changes me the last element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Hi everyone I come to you because I have a small problem, I create a dynamic comments system in ajax and I would like to edit each comment except that when I do it it changes me the last and not the element clicked
I've missed that things that I think

I have not tried anything yet I do not see how to do it

My code : 
js:

```
$('#edit-comments').hide();


$('#add-comments').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#formsComments').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#comments_commentsContent').val('');
            $('#content-comments').append(data.content);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.status === 500) {
                $('#errors-comments').html('<div class="error">Vous n\'avez pas ajouté de commentaires\n</div>')
            }
        }
    });

});

$('.comments-content').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#add-comments').hide();
    $('#edit-comments').show();

    var idEdit = $(this).attr('id');
    var idContent = idEdit.split('-');
    var res = $('p#comments-content-'+idContent[2]).text();
    console.log(idContent);

    $('#comments_commentsContent').val(res);

    $('#edit-comments').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/article/commentaires/'+idContent[2]+'/edit/'+idContent[3],
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#formsComments').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#comments_commentsContent').val('');
                $('#add-comments').show();
                $('#edit-comments').hide();

                $('#comments-content-'+idContent[2]).html(data.content.message);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My view twig :

```
 {% for comment in article.comments %}
                            <div class="media" id="media">
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <div class="media-heading">
                                        <h4>{{ comment.userComments.username }}</h4>
                                        <span class="time">{{ comment.createdAt | date("d/m/Y à H:i") }}</span>
                                        {% if app.user %}
                                            {% if comment.userComments.id == app.user.id %}
                                                <a href="{{ path('front_article_edit_comments', {'id': comment.id, 'user': comment.userComments.id}) }}#comments" class="comments-content" id="edit-comments-{{ comment.id }}-{{ comment.userComments.id }}" >
                                                    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
                                        <a href="{{ path('front_article_delete_comments', {'id': comment.id}) }}#comments" onclick="return confirm('Vous voulez vous vraiment supprimer ce commenaitre ?');">
                                            <i style="padding-left: 10px; color: #CBBBA3;" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    <p id="comments-content-{{ comment.id }}">{{ comment.commentsContent|nl2br }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
```

new comments :

```
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $comments->setUserComments($user);
            $comments->setArticleComments($articles);
            $em->persist($comments);
            $em->flush();

            $html = $this->renderView('articles/comments.html.twig', ['comment' => $comments]);

            return $this->json(['content' => $html]);
        }
```

edit comments :

```
 if($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->flush();

            return $this->json(['content' => [
                'message' => $comments->getCommentsContent(),
                'user' => $comments->getUserComments()->getId(),
                'id-comments' => $comments->getId(),
            ]]);
        }
```

When I want to edit the first comment or the second it does not work.

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: my form is classique form symfony

Comment: I would guess that the incorrect id is being passed where you have `data: $('#formsComments').serialize()` but you are not showing us that element or how it gets populated, I can only assume it is your form "classique form symfony" tells us nothing that we can use to help, you also have not shown us the complete controller actions for new/edit comments such as where you define the variable `$comments`.

Comment: how can send the parameter ?